# Generic insert stmt for multiple table with sequence numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I have a tricky situation. I need to create a generic insert script to move data from lower envt to higher envt(for Testing purpose).
I have three tables `tab1`, `tab2` and `tab3` and each table has sequence column(`tab1_col_ID`, `tab2_col_id` and `tab3_col_id`) where it contains sequence number in oracle and it shares the same sequence id(say `SID`).

below is the example:

```
tab1
tab1_col_id 
11
12

tab2
tab2_col_id
21
22

tab3
tab1_col_id,tab1_col_id,tab2_col_id
31,11,21
32,12,22
```

In `tab3`, `tab1_col_id` and `tab2_col_id` are foreign key of `tab1`(`tab1_col_id`) and `tab2`(`tab2_col_id`) table. `tab1_col_id`,`tab2_col_id` and `tab3_col_id` are numbers are generated via same sequence(`SID`). So, here `tab3` should contain `tab1` and `tab2` sequence numbers.

So, is there a way to make this as a generic insert script, where once I run, I'll be generating `INSERT INTO` stmts .

Comment: If you're moving the data from one environment to another, you can just use the existing id values - or am I missing something ?

Comment: Moving from Dev to UAT, so in UAT the sequence ID's will be different that of Dev. So I need to take sequence from UAT.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a script that uses the `RETURNING INTO` clause and do a row-by-row insert in the UAT environment. The generated script would look something like this (for a single row):

```
DECLARE
  l_tab1_col_id NUMBER;
  l_tab2_col_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tab1 (col1) VALUES ('x') RETURNING tab1_col_id INTO l_tab1_col_id;
  INSERT INTO tab2 (col1) VALUES ('xy') RETURNING tab2_col_id INTO l_tab2_col_id;
  INSERT INTO tab3 (tab1_col_id,tab2_col_id,col1) VALUES (l_tab1_col_id,l_tab2_col_id,'xyz');
END;
/
```

This will regenerate the primary keys and foreign keys and keep the relationship. But this is a slow and tedious operation. If it is an option, then I'd generate the insert statements with an offset so the generated ids are higher than the nextval on the UAT environment, run the insert and then alter the sequence.

Suppose the highest value of the sequence on UAT environment is 100, generated the insert statements based on the following selects:

```
SELECT tab1_col_id + 100, col1 FROM tab1;
SELECT tab2_col_id + 100, col1 FROM tab2;
SELECT tab3_col_id + 100, tab1_col_id + 100, tab2_col_id + 100, col1 FROM tab1;
```

After the insert statement on UAT has been run, alter the sequence to `START WITH` the highest value of tab1_col_id or tab1_col_id or tab1_col_id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Multirow insert will not work in my case. As I'm using sequence id's would be giving an issue. Suppose tab1(seq.id)->10 then for tab2(seq.id)->11( as seq_id.nextval) but in multirow, sequence will not update to next sequence.

Comment: What do you mean "multi row insert" are you referring to the first option (with the RETURNING INTO) or the 2nd option ?  Is the sequence value generated by a trigger ?

Comment: By multirow, I mean to say option1 and sequence is generated by sequence key. Basically my tab1 has 130 records and tab2 has 135 records and tab3 has got 130 records. So these many insert stmts will be generated for each table.

Comment: Option 1 is row-by-row. You need to execute that block for every row, that is meant by "row-by-row". It cannot be done for multiple rows at a time. If there are only 130 rows, then consider option 2. It is easier.

Comment: Just for clarification, tab1 and tab2 don't share same seq no, although seq name used by both table is same. They will have different seq no. So now, for tab3 "SELECT tab3_col_id + 100, tab1_col_id + 100, tab2_col_id + 100, col1 FROM tab1;" this condition will not hold true. Tab3 may contain SELECT 600(tab3_col_id),200(tab1_col_id),233(tab2_col_id). Basically, tab3 table contain seq id form tab1 and tab2 on basis of inner join query, where we join tab2 and tab1.

Comment: I understand the relationship. If table 1 has pk 1, table 2 has value 2 and table 3 has value 3, 2, 1 then the +100 will result in table1: 101, table2: 102 and table3: 103,102,101 - the relationship holds since you add the same offset to all columns. I suggest you give it a try.